# Question from BeautifulSoup when scraping from a table

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a question about scraping content from a table with BeautifulSoup. In the picure, I don't understand: "row = [i.text for i in td]". Why is i.text coming before the for loop? Thank you for any help! [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XF6G8.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called a list comprehension.

```
row = [i.text for i in td]
```

To break this down, it is the same as below but in more concise format and internally tends to be much faster to compute.

```
row = []
for i in td: 
    row.append(i.text)
```

See below for additional reading, essentially  it is much more concise way of creating a list.

[Real Python - List Comprehensions](https://realpython.com/list-comprehension-python/)

[Visual guide to list comprehensions](https://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/)